# Nested LINQ query using Contains with a bigint

Tags: linq, contains, biginteger, subquery

This is the SQL I want (`ClearinghouseKey` is a `bigint`):

```
select *
from ConsOutput O
where O.ClearinghouseKey IN (
  select distinct P.clearinghouseKey
  from Project P
  Inner join LandUseInProject L on L.ClearinghouseKey = P.ClearinghouseKey
  where P.ProjectLocationKey IN ('L101', 'L102', 'L103')
  and L.LandUseKey IN ('U000', 'U001', 'U002', 'U003')
)
```

The inner query is straight forward and gives correct results in LINQPad:

```
var innerQuery = (from p in Projects
                  join l in LandUseInProjects on p.ClearinghouseKey equals l.ClearinghouseKey
                  where locations.Contains(p.ProjectLocationKey) 
                  &&  (landuses.Contains(l.LandUseKey)) 
                  select new { p.ClearinghouseKey  }).Distinct();
```

But the outer query gives the error: Type arguments from ...Contains..cannot be inferred from usage:

```
var returnQuery = from o in OperOutput
                  where (innerQuery).Contains(o.ClearinghouseKey)
                  select o;
```

Is it because ClearinghouseKey is a bigint?  Any other ways to write this query?

Thanks,
Jeanne

Answer (score 5):

Don't use an anonymous type:

```
select new { p.ClearinghouseKey })
```

Should be

```
select p.ClearinghouseKey)
```

Also consider using Any instead of Contains (I don't have reasons for choosing one over the other, yet).

```
where innerQuery.Any(i => i == o.ClearinghouseKey)
```